# Fixing Mysql charset and data encoding issue

Tags: database, encoding, character-encoding, character, charset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v98ef.png)I was trying suitable charsets for my website, I had difficulties uploading some characters. Now it seems that the data encoding is gone strange, maybe chinese? It has only affected one column.

I have no clue how to fix this, it has affect 15k lines, the latest are not affected.

I don't know how to fix the issue.

Tried several charsets.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: Supposedly, you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'idontknow…'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-16-le')` returns `摩湯歴潮蕷`.